# Installed Ubuntu 12.04 - cannot visit certain websites I'm very familiar with

Tags: 12.04, firefox

Fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04, so far everything seems to be working except for this. Using FireFox 23 (the default browser) I get the following message:

Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

Could use some help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be a problem, considering worst case; let us suppose it isn't working. Why don't you go for latest Firefox version and Ubuntu 14.01/14.10? Current version of Firefox is 36.0.1, check what version you have. [IMP]Also check you Clock, sometimes due to security & privacy issues, browser blocks the websites which do not match time.

---

Well, Thats great @todd . Sorry, couldn't get to you in time. I would like to add that, make sure your Software updates are on, so that not only firefox, but also other softwares will get a stable release in every update.
Consider the foll. image,
[image: Software & Updates]
Make sure you have Main,Universe and Multiverse checked at the minimum in ***Softwares & Updates***. You can find that in your ***Applications*** menu.

Comment: Thank you for getting back. The time & date are correct. I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux. Yesterday I invested time reading & learn about Ubuntu/Linux. I did not know how to update FF or manually install a fresh version. My knowledge still shaking; much to learn. I installed Chrome; it works fine, but want to use FF. I’ve tried to install 14.04 with no luck; computer froze three lines after encountering **Starting Restore Sound Card State**. Not sure that 14.01 will install either… Please advise. I would prefer to install the latest version. Thanks

Comment: I've managed to install FF version 36 and that solved the problem with not being able to visit certain sites.

Comment: @todd if this answer solves the problem, you should accept it. Even if you figured it out for yourself before the answer was posted.